# me sale un error al copiar una hoja de google sheets a otra hoja con google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo dos spreadsheets diferentes en google sheets. Quiero copiar una columna de la spreadsheet A (hoja : NAMES_NODES) a la spreadsheet B (hoja : hoja 1).

Para no copiar y pegar manualmente voy a automatizarlo usando google app script. Pero me sale un error. Como lo podría corregir ?

Este es mi codigo :

```
function copyNames() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RiOmt0zeA5hDx5_Vo0FNL1pE7W5KwNErVMBkLmOZBM8");
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName("NAMES_NODES");
  var value = sheet.getRange(1,1,6,4).getValues();
  value.copyTo(destination);
}
```

El error dice :

> Error
> TypeError: value.copyTo is not a function

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que a la variable `value` se le ha asignado un objeto de tipo Array y dicho objeto no cuenta con el método `copyTo`.

Las clases [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) y [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) tienen métodos `copyTo`. Si bien el correspondiente a la clase Sheet permite copiar de un spreadsheet a otro, el correspondiente a Range me parece que sólo permite copiar en un mismo spreadsheet por lo que en lugar de usar copyTo quizás debas usar varios métodos para pegar los valores, los bordes de celda, color de fondo, etc.

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination